# Inner div dragable vertically, should allow parent div to be dragable horizontally

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have an outer div and an inner div. Inner div may be dragged vertically, and outer div may be dragged horizontally. I got this done ( http://jsfiddle.net/27Nh2/ )

Now I also want the outer div to be dragged horizontally if user tries to drag the inner div horizontally. The inner div should stay where it is inside the outer div while the outer div drags horizontally.

The problem is if I try to drag the inner div horizontally, nothing drags.

```
<div class="slides">
    Outer - only drag horizontally
    <div class="slide">
        Inner - only drag vertically
    </div>
</div>

.slides {
    margin:20px;
    background-color:#aaa;   
    cursor:pointer;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
.slide {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    margin:20px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

$(".slides").draggable({
    axis:"x",
});
$(".slide").draggable({
    axis:"y",
});
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you want the elements to move together, but restrict their movement to the x & y axis. Because otherwise `.draggable()` by itself would let you move both by clicking either.

Comment: The outer element is restricted to horizontal drag, the inner one is restricted to vertical drag. And when you click the inner element, you should be able to do a horizontal drag if the outer element is behind the inner element. And the inner element's position is relative to the outer one, so if the outer one drags horizontally, the inner one goes with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution that may work for you. As I understand your goal, this will keep the elements together but restrict them to one axis or the other.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/27Nh2/51/)**

JS:

```
$(".slides").draggable({
    axis:"x",
});

$('.slide').hover(
    function () {
        $('.slides').draggable({axis:'y'});
    },function () {
        $('.slides').draggable({axis:'x'});
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an alternative solution to this. It might not be able to move inner div both x and y axis at same time but by making use of **handle** option you can also move outer div when inner div is dragged horizontally:

```
<div class="slides">
<div class="slide">
    <p id="hd" style="border:2px solid;">Vertical</p>
    Hello World (horizontal)
</div>
```

```
$(".slides").draggable({
    axis:"x",
});
$(".slide").draggable({
    axis:"y",
    handle:"p"
});
```

Updated your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/27Nh2/22/)

Comment: Thanks Pruthvi. This is close to what I wanted. 
But I need a way for the inner ".slide" to not process the horizontal drag event and pass it to the parent ".slides" so it can handle it.

Comment: @rosewater By creating handle I restricted inner div draggable hence whenever you drag with rest of the inner div(except handle) then it will be considered as parent div drag event.

Answer (score 0):

I used your answer (badAdviceGuy) to get what I wanted, with some modification.

Now the inner div slides up/down and while you are inside the inner div, you can also slide the outer dive left/right.

Thanks.

I updated the jsFiddle ([http://jsfiddle.net/27Nh2/52/](http://jsfiddle.net/27Nh2/53/) )

```
var left = 0;
$(".outer").draggable({
    axis:"x",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        left = ui.position.left;
        $('#msg').html(ui.position.left);
    }
});
$(".inner").draggable({
    axis:"y",
    drag: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#msg').html(left + ui.position.left);
        $(".outer").css("left", left + ui.position.left);
    },
    stop : function(event, ui) {
        left = ui.position.left;
    }
});
```